# Aligning VideoOverlayScreen with Mesh camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

How do you properly place the Video overlay on the back of a meshing camera, so that the mesh generated matches what's seen in the video?

(Using Unity 5.2.1f3)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two important parts needed in order to make sure the video overlay align with the mesh:

1. The render camera's projection matrix

You have to make sure the projection matrix of your render camera matches the projection matrix of the physical camera. That requires a customized projection matrix calculated based on Tango color camera's intrinsics value. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoExamples/ExperimentalAugmentedReality/Scripts/ARScreen.cs#L303) is a snippet of sample code doing that (quoted from tango unity example). After the projection matrix is matched, the image you see will be aligned with the meshes.

2. Timestampe synchronization.

To be more precise on the rendering, you might want to do a synchronization between the point cloud, color camera, and the pose. To do that, you will need to query a pose based on color camera's update timestamp. Each time you received a point cloud, you need to transform the points to the color camera frame, because the point cloud is received in different timestamp. Then use the transformed point cloud to do the mesh reconstruction. Put it in a matrix equation:

`P_color = inverse(ss_T_color) * ss_T_depth* P_depth`